# Non-terminating Error Handling - Difference between if $Error.count and $ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'

Tags: powershell, error-handling, scripting, powershell-3.0

I need to handle a non-terminating error in a powershell script. What is the most efficient way to this?

To set `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to stop and use try/catch

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
try{
    functionThatCanFail
}catch{
    #Do Stuff
}
```

Or to clear `$Error` variable and then evaluate if it is populated

```
$Error.Clear()
functionThatCanFail
if( $Error.Count -ne 0){
    #Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use the **`-ErrorVariable` / `-ev` common parameter**, which records all non-terminating errors reported by a given cmdlet in a designated variable.

Note, however, that this **only works with *cmdlets* and *advanced functions*** / scripts, because only they support [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) - see [Patrick's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042427/45375) for how to define your own function as an *advanced* function.

```
# Provoke a non-terminating error and silence it, 
# but store it in custom variable $err via common parameter -ErrorVariable
Get-Item /NoSuchFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err

if ($err) { # if a / a least one non-terminating error was reported, handle it.
  "The following non-terminating error(s) occurred:`n$err"
}
```

That way, the **error analysis is command-scoped**, without having to record the state of or alter the state of the session-level `$Error` collection.

Note, however, that **you cannot handle *terminating* errors this way**.
For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell error handling, see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

Answer (score 3):

I would add `[CmdletBinding()]`to your function and put it inside a try/catch.
Because of the CmdletBinding you are now able to call your function with the parameter `-ErrorAction Stop`.
The other suggestion with the `$ErrorAction`or `$Error.Clear()`would also work but is not a 'clean' way.

```
function functionThatCanFail
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        $Param1
    )

    #Do stuff
}

try
{
    functionThatCanFail -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    #Error case
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation of why using `$Error.clear()` is not "clean"?

Comment: You would reset previous error messages and you have to add an other if-statement. That means more code and maybe you would like to handle the errors inside the $Error variable for further actions.